# Consequnces of Not Commiting a Hibernate Select Transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I am new to Hibernate and have inherited a code base that uses it. Auto-commit is not defined so it is by default false. Based on other questions I have asked though, answers have indicated that best practice is to demarcate the code such that if you begin a transaction you should always commit() or rollback() (Thanks to Apostolos). 
This code base uses the format in the below code for Select statements. I intend to properly demarcate any new code to commit() or rollback(), but I am just curious what the consequences would be for using the below model.The application has and continues to work alright, but I want to understand if there is any trouble with the existing code.

```
this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();    
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
session.clear();
entityReturned = (MultipleKeyTable) session.get(MultipleKeyTable.class, entityId);
session.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Session.close()` "End[s] the session by releasing the JDBC connection and cleaning up" ([Hibernate `SharedSessionContract` docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/SharedSessionContract.html#close--)).  That's not as explicit as I might like, but every plausible interpretation I can think of for "releasing the JDBC connection" implies ending any open transaction one way or another.  Still, just closing the session instead of explicitly ending the transaction is at best sloppy.

For what it's worth, [the `Session` docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html) recommend this idiom:

```
Session sess = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx = null;
try {
    tx = sess.beginTransaction();
    //do some work
    ...
    tx.commit();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
    throw e;
}
finally {
    sess.close();
}
```

If desired, you can run multiple transactions in the same session before closing it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several improvements I suggest:

1. Store **SessionFactory** rather a **Session** as member of your class: because you close session object after your job done you have no possibility to reuse this instance, so you will require new which can be retrived from **SessionFactory**;
2. Do not call **clear()** method: because you are using current session object calling **clear()** may drop all objects which are in persistence context but not yet flushed in database, so you can lost your data;
3. Commit or rollback transaction when you have done your job.

So the code have to be:

```
     this.sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
     Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();    
     Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

     entityReturned = (MultipleKeyTable) session.get(MultipleKeyTable.class, enti

     transaction.commit();
     session.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Calling close() after commit() will throw an exception though due to the session getting closed in the commit() call.